# cset shield --kthread on: should I use this?

Tags: linux, performance

I'm reading up on cpu shielding using Alex Tsariounov's `cset` utility here: https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Cpuset_Management_Utility/tutorial

In the tutorial I'm finding the wording around migrating kernel threads from having access to all cpus to running only in a certain cpuset a bit ambiguous

The tutorial says the following:

> Some kernel threads can be moved into the unshielded *system* cpuset as
>   well. These are the threads that are not bound to specific CPUs.
>
> If a kernel thread is bound to a specific CPU, then it is generally not a
>   good idea to move that thread to the *system* set because at worst it
>   may hang the system and at best it will slow the system down
>   significantly. These threads are usually the IRQ threads on a real
>   time Linux kernel, for example, and you may want to not move these
>   kernel threads into *system*. If you leave them in the *root* cpuset, then
>   they will have access to all CPUs.

The tutorial then goes on to say:

> However, if your application demands an even "quieter" shield, then you can move all movable kernel threads into the unshielded *system* set with the following command.

```
[zuul:cpuset-trunk]# cset shield -k on cset: --> activating kthread
shielding cset: kthread shield activated, moving 70 tasks into system
cpuset... [==================================================]% cset:
done
```

I am confused by this final sentence. By using the word *however*, it seems to suggest that you typically should **not** move the movable kernel threads into the unshielded *system* set.

Is this the case, or is it safe to move kernel threads which *can* be moved into a cpuset, thereby preventing them from running on some cpus?